# Can Spark operate on a 64 Bit Double within Cassandra using JAVA

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using spark to perform some statistical analysis on a 64 bit double from a Cassandra table column of type: double

**Example:**

> 5.084936038014788E8

When I perform the analysis it returns nothing.  After looking at the [Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) data types I see that it SHOULD support 64 bit double precision:

> DoubleType: Represents 8-byte double-precision floating point numbers

If I use a smaller precision:

> 5.0849E8

it works fine.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, size(double) == 8byte == 64bit (8*8=64)

Comment: That's why I don't know why it's not working.  I've reworded question to better express that.

Comment: Ok got it, what analysis are you performing and what do you mean by "it returns nothing"?

Comment: I am taking a row of data and running a min,max, avg  on one of the columns `sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(values), Value.class).groupBy(col("channel"))
        .agg(min("power"), max("power"), avg("power"))
        .write().mode(SaveMode.Append)      
        .option("table", "results")
        .option("keyspace", "model")
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").save();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with my calculation algorithm and not spark itself.